# ID should not display between the specified date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Using SQL Server 2000

Database1.Table1

```
ID  Name Date       title    
001 Ravi 23-02-2009 Accountant
001 Ravi 24-02-2009 Accountant
001 Ravi 25-02-2009 Accountant
002 Ram  21-02-2009 Supervisors
002 Ram  25-02-2009 Supervisors
002 Ram  26-02-2009 Supervisors
```

So on…,

Database2.Table2

```
ID  Name Date1      Date2    
001 Ravi 23-02-2009 24-02-2009 
002 Ram  21-02-2009 24-02-2009
```

So on…

Suppose I want to display the records from 21-02-2009 to 26-02-2009 -
Expected Output:

```
001 Ravi 25-02-2009 Accountant
002 Ram 25-02-2009 Supervisors
002 Ram 26-02-2009 Supervisors
```

From the above two table I want to display id, name, date, title from Database1.table1 where Database1.table1.id should not display between date1 and date2 from Database2.table2:

```
(23-02-2009 to 24-02-2009) ID should not display from table1
(21-02-2009 24-02-2009) ID should not display from table1
```

How to make a query in SQL?

Can any one help me.

Comment: Perhaps if you could show us the code you have written so far? People don't generally like to just write your code for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every row in Table1 we look for row in Table2 and show only rows with no Table2 match:

```
SELECT
  TABLE1.*
FROM TABLE1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2
ON 
  (TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID) AND --JOIN TABLE2 BY ID
  (TABLE1.DATE BETWEEN TABLE2.DATE1 AND TABLE2.DATE2) --AND BY DATE CRITERIA
WHERE 
  (TABLE2.ID IS NULL) AND --SHOW ONLY IF IT DIDN'T MATCH ROW IN TABLE2
  (TABLE1.DATE BETWEEN '21-02-2009' AND '26-02-2009')
```

Comment: Showing Error as "cannot resolve collation conflict for equal to operation"

Comment: Are you storing dates as text? This is not good idea. My SQL was just to show how it should be made, but dates should not be stored in text. If You store it in text, You should change it. If You cannot change it, You can use CONVERT function to change text to date and then compare. CONVERT(DATETIME,TABLE1.DATE,110) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,'21-02-2009',110) AND CONVERT(DATETIME,'26-02-2009',110) Read here about convert: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT t.id, 
       t.name, 
       t.date, 
       t.title
  FROM TABLE_1 t
 WHERE NOT EXIST(SELECT NULL
                   FROM TABLE_2 t2
                  WHERE t.date BETWEEN t2.date1 AND t2.date2)
```

If your data model stores dates at strings, update the NOT EXISTS to use CAST/CONVERT to change them to DateTime...

Mind that [LEFT JOIN/IS NULL is not as efficient as NOT IN/NOT EXISTS in SQL Server](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/).

Answer (score 0):

i *think* you're looking for this:

```
select db1.id, db1.name, db1.date, db1.title
from database1.table1 as db1
    join database2.table2 as db2 on db1.id = db2.id
where db1.date < db2.date1
    or db1.date > db2.date2
```

-don